# How to choose variable to display in tooltip when using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a simple data frame:

```
seq <- 1:10
name <- c(paste0("company",1:10))
value <- c(250,125,50,40,40,30,20,20,10,10)
d <- data.frame(seq,name,value)
```

And I want to plot it this way:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = d,aes(x=seq,y=value))+geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Now I want to use plotly, mostly to be able, when mousing over a point, to get other information than the value, such as the company name. I try this :

```
require(plotly)
ggplotly()
```

which get me a tooltip, but with only seq and value. I tried the option tooltip= but it's specified you can use the only variable describe in the aesthetic, and I don't use the name in my aes.

Any solution? I saw I am not the first with this problem, but I haven't found answer working with ggplotly.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You don't need to modify the `plotly` object as suggested by @royr2. Just add `label = name` as third aesthetic

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = seq, y = value, label = name)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

and the tooltip will display `name` in addition to `seq` and `value`.

The `ggplotly` help file says about `tooltip` parameter:

> The default, "all", means show all the aesthetic mappings (including the unofficial "text" aesthetic).

So you can use the `label` aesthetic as long as you don't want to use it for `geom_text`.

BTW: I've also tried `text` instead of `label`

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = seq, y = value, text = name)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

but then `ggplot2` complained

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

and plotted only points. I had to add a dummy group to `geom_line` to remove the issue:

```
ggplot(data = d, aes(x = seq, y = value, text = name)) + geom_line(group = 1) + geom_point()
```

(But note if you put the dummy group as fourth aesthetic inside `aes()` it will appear by default also in the tooltip.)

However, I find the unofficial `text` aesthetic can become useful alongside `label` if you want to have different strings plotted by `geom_text` and shown in the tooltip.

**Edit to answer a question in comments:** 
The `tooltip` parameter to `ggplotly()` can be used to control the appearance. `ggplotly(tooltip = NULL)` will suppress tooltips at all. `ggplotly(tooltip = c("label"))` selects the aesthetics to include in the tooltip.

Comment: thank you, this seems to me to be a more readable way of obtaining what I want. If someone want to use geom_text, then aes should be put directly in geom_line and in geom_text.

Comment: Is it possible to also remove the default labels in addition to adding others?

Comment: @VisionIncision Yes. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @UweBlock Thank you for your assistance thus far.

Sorry I should have been clearer, for some reason with the way I am creating a plot (possibly because I am doing it with shiny), it does not seem to make a difference if I use any tooltips arguments. So I was wondering if there was something I could do in the aes() function, like how you can add them with label=, label2= etc to remove default labels.

Comment: @JackH I struggled with this for a while. Remember to use the name of the *aesthetic*, **not** your variable, in the call to tooltip. For example, use `"x"` not `"seq"` and `"label"` not `"name"`.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166106/r-error-first-argument-data-must-be-a-data-frame-or-shared-data thanks!

Comment: I found that if you use `label = name` the tooltip info will show `name: companyX`, whereas if you use `text = name` the tooltip will just show `companyX`. This was useful for me because I had already created the tooltip info in it's own column using `str_c('Line 1: ', line1_col, '<br> Line 2: ', line2_col', ...)` and when using `label = ` it annoyingly included the name of the column at the beginning of the label.

Answer (score 62):

Building on @UweBlock's answer, you can also create dummy aesthetics in order to display multiple labels in tooltips.  I can't find where this is documented, but discovered it emperically.  The dummy variables show up in the order you specify them, but priority is given to the default variables (e.g. x and y).  To get around this, you can specify those variables in a separate aesthetic, as shown below:

```
library(plotly)
p = ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species, label2=Petal.Length, label3=Petal.Width)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: This really works. I have a quick question, is there any way to order the tooltip? I mean x and y axis will be first and then the other labels?

Comment: @Joy it seems to want to put x and y first, unless you move them to the geom_point's aes: `p = ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species, label2=Petal.Length, label3=Petal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))`.  The resulting plot will show the tooltips in the order they appear in the command.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am getting error: argument 3 is not a vector. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure; I pasted that line into R (version 3.2.5) and got the expected plot. I'm using plotly version 3.4.13 and ggplot2 version 2.1.0. See my updated answer for the full script.

Comment: this is still working in R v4.0.3. I really wish I could up vote this post twice because it's an awesome trick

Answer (score 41):

The unofficial `text` aesthetic allows you to introduce all the variables you want (here I use `name` twice to show it):

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = d,aes(x = seq, 
                    y = value,
                    group = 1,
                    text = paste('name: ', name,
                                 '</br>name_again: ', name)
                    ))+
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

I have to add a dummy `group` aesthetic for the `geom_line` to work properly as @UweBlock suggested.

At last I choose what I want to show in the tooltip (here I excluded `group`).

```
require(plotly)
ggplotly(, tooltip = c("x", "y", "text"))
```

Comment: Introducing the "text" in aes() really solved my problem. THANK YOU!!

Comment: This feels like black magic but it works!

Comment: That works fine, but is there a clean way (not suppressWarnings) to suppress "Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text"

Answer (score 15):

You'll have to modify the `plotly object` to do this. Or use `plot_ly()` to create the graph instead...

EDIT:
With the release of `plotly 4.0` the syntax will change a little bit.

```
seq <- 1:10
name <- c(paste0("company",1:10))
value <- c(250,125,50,40,40,30,20,20,10,10)
d <- data.frame(seq,name,value)

require(plotly)
gg <- ggplot(data = d,aes(x=seq,y=value))+geom_line() + geom_point()

gg <- plotly_build(gg)

#OLD:
gg$data[[1]]$text <- paste("Seq:", d$seq, "<br>",
                           "Value:", d$value, "<br>",
                           "Company:", d$name)

#UPDATED: 
#Plotly_build creates two separate traces:
#One with mode = markers and the other with mode = lines
#Hence modify text for the second trace

gg$x$data[[2]]$text <- paste("Seq:", d$seq, "<br>",
                           "Value:", d$value, "<br>",
                           "Company:", d$name)

gg
```

Comment: great, it works thank you ! I will give plot_ly() a look too, I imagine this can give more readable code, but this way I am not compulsed to update all my code !

Comment: This solution works for me locally but when I place the app on shiny server the additional tooltip is not there. Then I tried the solution below and that works.

Comment: @royr2 still no dice -"company" does not appear in tooltip

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian seems okay for me - I am using `plotly v4.0.1`

Comment: @royr2 interesting, I'm on version 3.6.0, I just reinstalled it from CRAN and it's still that same version, are you installing from github?

Comment: I've updated plotly by installing it from github, it works now for the example above but when used with a ggplot choropleth map (geom_polygons), it adds an additional tooltip box and keeps the previous one as well...very odd behavior

Comment: How to make it work with facets present? It works only in the 1st facet for me.

Comment: you need to run through all of them. So you can make a for loop (lets say with i in....) where you change gg$data[[i]]$text. Seems in plotly 4.5.6.9000 you need to change gg$x$data instead of gg$data.