# Change hover over values in a plotly plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the following Shiny Application:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I now hoover over a point I get values like: (14.5, 17.3). Is there an easy way to make sure these values appear as:

mpg: 12.3 [enter]
wt: 45.2

Comment: You should find the answer you need for customising the tooltip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49460271/9552161).

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#custom-hover-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following does what you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, 
            x = ~mpg, 
            y = ~wt,  
            hoverinfo="text", 
            text = ~paste0("mpg: ", mpg, "\nwt: ", wt))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Hope this helps!