# number instead of date on the density plot in R

Tags: r, plotly, density-plot, r-plotly, ggplotly

I have a problem. I am trying to draw a density plot in R with the `plotly` package. But when I hover the mouse over the plot I get number format of date 17623 instead 2018-04-02. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
Date <- seq(as.Date(Sys.Date()-30), by=1, len=31)
Value <- runif(31)
dataTable <- data.frame(Date, Value)

density_plot = ggplot(dataTable, aes(x=Date, y = Value)) +
  geom_density(stat="identity", fill = "#4156C5") + 
  labs(fill = "Value", x = "Date", y = "Frequency")
ggplotly(density_plot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this: [how to choose variable to display in tooltip when using ggplotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly)

You could try this:

```
density_plot = ggplot(dataTable, aes(x=Date, y = Value, label1= Date, label2 = Value)) +
  geom_density(stat="identity", fill = "#4156C5") + 
  labs(fill = "Value", x = "Date", y = "Frequency")

ggplotly(density_plot, tooltip = c("label1", "label2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it is what I am looking for, thank you!
I have one more question, how to remove the black border of the plot?

Comment: you can play with the color (`color = "white"`) or size as in `geom_density(stat="identity", fill = "#4156C5", size = 0)`.