# How to add more info to the tooltip on interactive plot generated by ggplotly (from ggplot) in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to generate a interactive plot with `ggplotly` package. 
I generated a plot with `ggplot` and use `ggplotly` function to make it interactive.  I wonder how I can add more info to the tooltip.
Here is the example:

```
df=data.frame(id=rep(1:5, each=2),
           grp = rep(1:2, each=5),
           grp2 = rep(c('A','B'), 5),
           grp3 = LETTERS[1:10],
           value1 = runif(10),
           value2 = rnorm(10))
g=df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=grp3, y=value1, text=id))+ 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')

ggplotly(g, tooltip = c('grp3', 'value1','id', 'value2', 'grp1'))
```

The tooltip only shows `grp3`, `value1` and `id`.

My question is:

1:  How can I show other info like `value2`, `grp1` etc?

2: How can I format the tooltip? For example, I want to show `id: xxx`, instead of just a number.

I want to use `ggplotly` function to achieve this, since it's so convenient to convert a ggplot to interactive plot.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use dummy aesthetics to show multiple labels in tooltips?

```
ggplot(aes(x=grp3, y=value1, label=id, label2=value2, label3=grp))
```

[How to choose variable to display in tooltip when using ggplotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly)