# R ggplotly shows wrong tooltip with geom_sf() and discrete fill scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-sf, ggplotly

I'm trying to create maps that'll show tooltips on hover with plotly. In the maps below, I've tried to make it show the name and the area of each place.

The first map, which has a continuous fill scale, shows the tooltip I'm asking for. But the second map, doesn't. The only difference is that the fill scale is discrete.

What's going on, and how can I fix it?

```r
library(pacman)
p_load(sf, ggplot2, dplyr, plotly)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
    mutate(x = factor(c(rep("a", 50), rep("b", 50))),
           TEXT = paste(NAME, AREA))

# It works when I've got a continuous fill scale
p1 <- nc %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA, text = TEXT))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text") %>% 
    style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), hoveron = "text")
```

[image: map showing the correct tooltip]

Why does this map say "a"?

```r
# But it doesn't work with a discrete fill scale
p2 <- nc %>% 
    ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = x, text = TEXT))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

ggplotly(p2, tooltip = "text") %>% 
    style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"), hoveron = "text")
```

[image: map showing the wrong tooltip]

**EDIT**: turns out even the continuous map sometimes shows weird tooltips. Some areas show the right one, as above, others show "Trace XX":

[image: continuous map showing wrong tooltip in some areas]

Comment: I have had different results when I use a continuous fill too. It seems there's a separate "trace" layer for every color/fill.

Comment: This blog post with code shows what we want but I can't reproduce it https://blog.cpsievert.me/2018/01/30/learning-improving-ggplotly-geom-sf/

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined the `tooltip` content using `text = TEXT`. Just remove `hoveron = "text"` and everything will be OK. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly) post for more info.

```
p1 <- nc %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA, text = TEXT))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

ggplotly(p1, tooltip = "text") %>% 
  style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"))
```

[image]

```
p2 <- nc %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = x, text = TEXT))
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

ggplotly(p2, tooltip = "text") %>% 
  style(hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That gets me very close, but now the tooltip only shows up when you hover over the lines, not the interior of the areas. And because the lines for neighbouring areas are drawn on top of one another, you can't get some of the tooltips to show, no matter where you hover. E.g. Cabarrus, the downward-facing triangle, five counties to the West of Harnett.

Comment: Not sure about why is that happening. Looks like I can't get around that one!

Comment: You can get the hover behavior you want by adding a `style(hoveron = "fill")`

Comment: I've also gotten different behaviour when I use ggplotly() %>% style(hoveron = "fills")

Comment: The workaround is shared here:
https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1641#issuecomment-550477069