# How to customize hover info while using ggplotly() from plotly package in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I am adding a layer of points to a plot made originally in `ggplot2` but that I transformed through
`plotly` package into a plotly object. The hover shows info I do not need (points coordinates) and there is a couple o variables that I need to show its values but I can't find the way to do it.

The next example shows my problem. I converted a `ggplot2` graph into a `plotly` one, as is shown below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width))+
        geom_smooth()
ggplotly(p1)
```

Then I wanted to add a layer with some points and put certain information in the hover so I could identify which species each point is. I mean I want the Species info to appear in the hover without putting the variable Species in the aesthetics of the `ggplot()` function.

The closest I've been is this but it does not work either:

```
ggplotly(p1) %>%
        add_markers(data=iris[1:10,], x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Petal.Width) %>%
        style(hoverlabel="Species")
```

I want to know if is it possible placing values of other variables in the hover that are not part of the aesthetics set and if can I take off the ones I do not need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following will add the species to the existing label:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width))+
  geom_smooth()

ggplotly(p1) %>%
  add_markers(data=iris[1:10,], x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Petal.Width) %>% 
  style(hovertext=iris[1:10,"Species"])
```

There is also a nice answer to a similar question about building the tooltip text into the aesthetic element of the ggplot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly).  In the bit of testing I did, if you specify the variable in the `label` in the points aesthetic, then `ggplotly(p1)` will add that to the existing label.  If you instead, call `ggplotly(p1, tooltip="label")` that will just print the `Species: <species>` in the tooltip.  If instead of `label` you specify `text` in the points aesthetic, and call `ggplotly(p1, tooltip="text")`, you will just get the species name itself in the tooltip.

Comment: using `style` function worked well in the Iris example I posted but it did not work in my real life example where I am using the `ggmap` function for creating a map and then adding some points of interest with the labels I wanted. R creates the plot but some labels in the hover were repeated once and another in points where it did not suppose to appear. The solution was the second tip, the link you referred to use the argument `label=` as an argument in the aesthetics and then call it in the `tooltip` named argument.