# How to choose a variable to display via the tooltip of ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I am trying to do something similar to this [How to choose variable to display in tooltip when using ggplotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly)

But the difference is I have two time series and the solution suggested in that link doesn't work. So this is what I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)


t = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
x = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
y = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
z = rnorm(10, 0, 1)

df = data.frame(t,x,y,z)

p = df %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(t, x, text = paste(z)), color = "red") +
                  geom_point(aes(t, y), color = "blue")

ggplotly(p , tooltip = "z")
```

I want to show the value of z when I hover on the points. Any idea how to do that here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `tooltip` argument with a vector of variables/aesthetics of the `ggplot` object (e.g. x, y, size, fill, colour...), not columns from your original dataframe (which is what you did).

You are mapping the values of `z` to `text` in `geom_point` (which does not exist in ggplot, so you should be getting a warning). So just set `tooltip = "text"` (note that the blue points will have no tooltips in this case, because you did not set the `text` aesthetic there)

```
p = df %>% ggplot() + geom_point(aes(t, x, text = paste(z)), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(t, y), color = "blue")

ggplotly(p , tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

From the help page of `ggplotly` (you can read this by typing `? ggplotly` in the R console)

> tooltip

> a character vector specifying which aesthetic mappings to show in the tooltip. The default, "all", means show all the aesthetic mappings (including the unofficial "text" aesthetic). The order of variables here will also control the order they appear. For example, use tooltip = c("y", "x", "colour") if you want y first, x second, and colour last.

---

**EDIT:** with `geom_line`

When you use the unofficial `text` aesthetic in `geom_line` it messes up with the grouping of the points (see discussion in the [link at the beginning of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly)). One fix for this is to explicitly tell `geom_line` to group all points together by adding the `group=1` parameter.

```
p = df %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(t, x, text = paste(z), group=1), color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(t, y), color = "blue")

ggplotly(p , tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kikoralston , but do you know why your approach doesn't work when using geom_line instead of geom_point?

Comment: I did not know this. But if you look at the link in your post, you will see that they discuss this issue too. Apparently, when you add the `text=...` inside `geom_line`, it messes up the grouping of the data points for some reason. It puts each point of the red line in a different group and because it draws lines with just one point, the red line does not appear. One quick solution is to explicitly tell 'geom_line' that all points should be grouped together in the same line by adding the parameter `group=1`. I edited the answer with a `geom_line` example.