# How to show variables not used for plotting in ggplotly on hover?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Suppose I have 5 variables in a data frame used for plotting using ggplot.
I have used 3 out of 5 variables for plotting. When I hover over the scatter plot, I only see 3 variables shown.

Question: How can I show variable 4 along with the other three while hovering?

### Sample Example

Using Iris Data set:

```
p1 <- 
  iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) 
ggplotly(p1)
```

How to get Petal.Length info also displayed while hovering?
Image below shows what is currently being shown on hover.

[image: The output currently seen is attached in the image.]

Comment: Realized that this question is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplotly` offers a `text` "aesthetic" or attribute which could be used to show additional data columns in the tooltip:

```
library(plotly)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species,
    text = paste0("Petal.Length: ", Petal.Length)
  )) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)
ggplotly()
```

[image]